# Percentage widths of floating div tags

Tags: html, floating

I am kind of new to this but I figured the best way to explain my situation was to draw it out so here is the image of what I am trying to do http://d.pr/i/5ez3

Basically is there anyway to have floating divs re-size once they collapse and the browser window gets smaller.

Comment: Please show us an attempt, and some code depicting your attempt? Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use media queries to break down at what width the divs should take when the width of browser falls below some particular width.

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/